# Reading the same file with several different streams in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, stream

Is it possible to read a file using multiple streams to access different portions of data in it at the same time, using Qt?

Comment: Just open the file multiple times.

Comment: You mean like this? `QTextStream out1(&File); QTextStream out2(&File);`

Comment: i tried it - the second stream outputs garbage

Comment: @VisViva This is the problem: you need two devices (file1, file2) operating on the same (physical) file. See my answer for details.

Comment: @VisViva: Thats what I meant when I said open it multiple times. Open multiple QFile objects on the same path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that a stream (QTextStream / QDataStream) in Qt doesn't handle the position in the underlying device. A stream class is only a wrapper for easier parsing of the binary data within the device (QFile instance).

So two streams for the same device (QFile) will not work.

You can, however, have **multiple devices** (QFile) for the same underlying file, and each of them can then be read using another stream instance.