# Modify an XML file QXMLStreamReader/Writer

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on something where I am using `QXMLStreamReader` and `QXMLStreamWriter`, to read and write to a file.

But am not able to find a way such that I can modify an XML, for example consider this XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LAMPS>
    <LIGHT1>
        <State>statevalue</State>
        <Room>roomvalue</Room>
        <Potencial>potencialvalue</Potencial>
    </LIGHT1>
</LAMPS>
```

This is written using the following code :

```
QFile file(filename);
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

QXmlStreamWriter xmlWriter(&file);
xmlWriter.setAutoFormatting(true);
xmlWriter.writeStartDocument();

xmlWriter.writeStartElement("LAMPS");

xmlWriter.writeStartElement("LIGHT1");
xmlWriter.writeTextElement("State", "statevalue" );
xmlWriter.writeTextElement("Room", "roomvalue");
xmlWriter.writeTextElement("Potencial", "potencialvalue");
xmlWriter.writeEndElement();
xmlWriter.writeEndElement();
file.close();
```

Now I want to add one more `<LIGHT1>` to an EXISTING xml file, then how is possible to do that in QT?

I am doing the following:

```
     //filename = my file path
     QFile file(filename);
     file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
     QXmlStreamWriter xmlWriter(&file);
     QXmlStreamReader xmlReader;
     xmlReader.setDevice(&file);
     xmlWriter.setAutoFormatting(true);
     while(!xmlReader.atEnd()){
         if(xmlReader.isStartDocument())
             xmlWriter.writeStartDocument();
         if(xmlReader.isStartElement()){
             xmlWriter.writeStartElement(xmlReader.name().toString());
             if(xmlReader.name()=="LAMPS"){
                 xmlWriter.writeStartElement("Arqam");
                 xmlWriter.writeTextElement("Arqam","Lucid Dreamer");
                 xmlWriter.writeEndElement();
             }
         }
         if(xmlReader.isEndElement())
             xmlWriter.writeEndElement();
         if(xmlReader.isEndDocument())
             xmlWriter.writeEndDocument();
         xmlReader.readNext();
         file.close();
```

And I am getting the following errors :

```
QIODevice::write (QFile, "/Users/arqam/Desktop/XMLGenrator/input/zzzz.xml"): device not open
QIODevice::read (QFile, "/Users/arqam/Desktop/XMLGenrator/input/zzzz.xml"): device not open
```

Comment: According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710598/reading-the-same-file-with-several-different-streams-in-qt) it is not possible to have multiple stream for a single device.

Comment: You’re closing the input file in the while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QDomDocument` to store content from XML. You can create new child, tag, attribute.

```
#include <QXmlStreamReader>
#include <QXmlStreamWriter>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDomElement>
#include <QDomDocument>
#include <QDomText>
#include <QTextStream>

int main()
{
    QFile file("test.xml");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to open file";
        return 0;
    }
    QDomDocument document;
    if (!document.setContent(&file))
    {
        qDebug() << "failed to parse file";
        file.close();
        return 0;
    }

    file.close();

    QDomElement docEle = document.documentElement();
    QDomNodeList elements = docEle.elementsByTagName("LAMPS");

    QDomElement light1 = document.createElement( "LIGHT1" );
    QDomElement state = document.createElement("State");
    QDomText nextNode = document.createTextNode("State");
    state.appendChild(nextNode);
    light1.appendChild(state);
    docEle.appendChild( light1 );

    QFile outFile( "test-result.xml" );
    if( !outFile.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text ) )
    {
        qDebug( "Failed to open file for writing." );
        return 0;
    }

    QTextStream stream( &outFile );
    stream << document.toString();

    outFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess using `QDomDocument` is the only solution in these cases.

Comment: @arqam Not only way. You can also write the new XML to a memory buffer or temp file while reading the original, then replace the original with the new one after it's complete. But if the XML is small enough to fit into memory (say, at most some hundreds of megabytes on a PC), then using DOM is better.